# Laravel 5.2 eloquent query

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

i have 2 table `Jobs` and `Departments` (a job belong to a department) and i want to get some jobs with its department.
Here is the code i have to modify:

```
    $query = Job::query()->where('status', 2);

    if($input['title']!=""){
        $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $input['title'] . '%')->get();
    }
    if($input['location'] != ""){
        $query->where('location', '=', $input['location']);
    }
    if($input['recruiters'] != ""){
        $query->where('recruiter_id','=', $input['recruiters']);
    }

    $jobs = $query->paginate(5);
    return $jobs;
```

`query` variable don't have method `join` for me. I try `with` but it not work.
There are any solution for `join` or to make other query via `DB` but `title,location,recruiters` variables is not always be set.
Sorry for my bad English and thanks for your consider.

Comment: In this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) you can see how to join tables.

Comment: yah, thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Eloquent Relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

You basically define the relationship between Job and Depertment in the Model and later call `$job->department()->name` (this is an example call) to get the name of the attached department.